# Error 401 Not authorised in Invoke URL for data accessed via SAP gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, sap-gateway, aws-nlb

I am trying to enable the SAP data access over the internet by implementing the following environment. This setup is as per the AWS solution as mentioned in the URL : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/awsforsap/deploy-apis-for-sap-using-amazon-api-gateway/

[image]

Post setting up the above environment in AWS console, The SAP data is accessible inside the VPC network using DNS name of Network Load Balancer. I verified by accessing it from a browser in EC2 instance by passing the SAP username and password in a pop-up window.

However, the invoke URL generated using the AWS API console, post executing the “deploy API”, the URL is not loading the SAP data as required, its giving output of 401 not authorized.

Tried to pass on the username and password using headers as well using query strings in API gateway console, but no luck